# Making a body background image with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css

I use this to set the size and it works well for abstract images that can handle some x-y distortion.

```
body{
  background:  url('foo/images/flowers.jpg');
  background-size:  100%;
}
```

However as content expands downward this does not work as the image begins to repeat.

I noticed that twitter has one image that does not change no matter how far you scroll down.

It behaves like

```
position: fixed
```

I could use a div with a background image and position fixed but then I would loose the automatic scaling provided by the `body` tag combined with `background-size: 100%`

Comment: Try `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `background-attachment` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment) with a value of `fixed`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#element { 
  background: #fff url("http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Scitech/660/371/tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg?ve=1");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wJYPn/)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```